# The second and third derivitive tests give unexpected $0$

Tags: calculus

The final question on a [mock paper](http://filestore.aqa.org.uk/subjects/AQA-83602-QP-JUN14.PDF) I recently did was the following:

> The curve $y=f(x)$ has $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=kx(x-3)^3$, where k is a **negative** constant.
>
> There is a stationary point at $x=3$
>
> Classify this stationary point.

My thought process:
$$\begin{align}
\text{Find the nature of the point}\\
f'(x)  & = kx(x-3)^3 \\
       & = kx(x^3-9x^2+27x-27) \\
       & = kx^4-9kx^3+27kx^2-27kx \\
f''(x) & = 4kx^3-27kx^2+54kx-27k \\
f''(3) & = 4k\cdot(3)^3-27k\cdot(3)^2+54k\cdot(3)-27k \\
       & = 0 \\
& \therefore x=3 \text{ is an inflection.} \\
\text{Find the direction of inflection} \\
f'''(x)& = 12kx^2-54kx+54k \\
f'''(3)& = 12k\cdot(3)^2-54k\cdot(3)+54k \\
       & = 0
\end{align}$$

If $f'''(x)>0$ it is an increacing inflection, $f'''(x)<0$ it is decreacing inflection, but $f'''(3)=0$ gives me no information.

After the paper, I found that nobody else used the second derivitive method and all found the point was a maximum. Did I make an error in differentiation, or do the second and third derivitives sometimes not work?

Edit: the mark scheme mentions the fourth derivitive, but doesn't explain why it's used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if a point is a point of inflection (using derivatives as opposed to comparing gradients) you need the lower-order non-zero derivative to be odd. If the lower-order non-zero derivative is even then you have an undulation point.

If you evaluate $f''''(3)$ you'll get $18k$ so the point is not a point of inflection but is instead an undulation point.

[Further reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point#A_necessary_but_not_sufficient_condition)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the second derivative test doesn't always work. If $f(x)=x^{20}$, $x=0$ is clearly the location of a local minimum. But $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for *all* $n$ less than 20. If $f''(x)$ is zero at a stationary point, this can mean an inflection point, but it doesn't have to. This is one case where the second derivative test is inconclusive.

Comment: Why $n<20$, or is it too long of an explanation for a comment?

Comment: the $n$th derivative of $x^{20}$ for $n<20$ is $\frac{20!}{(20-n)!}x^{20-n}$. If we evaluate this at $x=0$, we get $0$. If $n=20$, the derivative is $20!$, a constant. If $n>20$, the derivative is identically $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your fellow students were right: The function $f$ does not have a point of inflection there. As a matter of fact, the *derivative* that we see does have a point of inflection, but the question is about the function itself.

Recall that it is *sufficient* for a local maximum that $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)<0$. As well it is *sufficient* for an increasing point of inflection to have $f''(x)=0$ and $f'''(x)>0$. However, these conditions are not *necessary*. Here we have an example that shows that sometimes we have to dig deeper: The more general case is that we have $f'(x)=f''(x)=\ldots =f^{(n)}(x)=0$ and $f^{(n+1)}(x)\ne 0$.

- If in such a case, $n$ is odd, then we have a local extremum (and the sign of $f^{(n+1)}(x)$ decides between minimum and maximum: $f^{(n+1)}(x)<0$ means local maximum, $f^{(n+1)}(x)>0$ means local minimum).
- If on the other hand $n$ is even, then our stationary point is a point of inflection. (And again $f^{(n+1)}(x)$ determines the type of inflection).
- For completeness' sake, it is possible that a function is infinitely differentiable and that *all* derivatives are $=0$ at some point without $f$ being constant. The function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}ae^{-1/x}&x>0\\be^{1/x}&x<0\\0&x=0\end{cases}$$ has this property at $x=0$ and by choice of $a,b$ we can make that point a local minimum or maximum or a point of inflection.
- Not to mention that also functions that are not differentiable as often as the *sufficient* criteria need can have local extrema. Just look at $f(x9=|x|$, where $f'(0)$ does not exist.

So back to the problem at hand: Since we find $f'(3)=f''(3)=f'''(3)=0$, we should compute $f''''(3)$ and see what happens.

Alternatively, we forget about the *standard* methods to check for local extrema and verify directly that $f(x)<f(3)$ for all $x$ with $x>0$ and $x\ne 3$. Indeed, for such $x$ we have
$$f(x)-f(3)=(x-3)f'(\xi)=(x-3)\cdot kx(\xi-3)^3 $$
where $\xi$ is between $x$ and $3$. In particular, $x-3$ and $\xi-3$ have the same sign. Hence $f(x)-f(3)$ is $kx$ times the product of four non-zero numbers of same sign, i.e, $kx$ times something positive, i.e., something negative (because $k$ is negative and $x$ is positive). Hence $f(x)<f(3)$ as claimed.